# Why this '/' in my json

Tags: python

I have this

```
import json

header = """{"fields": ["""

print(header)

with open('fields.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(header, outfile)
```

and the return of print it's ok:

```
{"fields": [
```

but what is in the fields.json it's

```
"{\"fields\": ["
```

Why and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Escape sequence for the quote char

Comment: They are escape characters, they are there to escape the quotes

Comment: What are you actually trying to archive with the header?

Comment: Your question title asks about "/", but your data shows "\". Which are you asking about, because those two characters have very different meanings in certain contexts.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue there. The `\` in the file is to escape the `"`. To see this read the `json` back and print it. So to add to your code

```
import json

header = """{"fields": ["""

print(header)

with open('C:\\Users\\tkaghdo\\Documents\\fields.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(header, outfile)

with open('C:\\Users\\tkaghdo\\Documents\\fields.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

print(data)
```

you will see the data is printed as `{"fields": [`

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you are trying to write is bring treated as a string 
so `"` is converted to `\"` . to avoid that we need to decode json using `json.loads()` before writing to file

**The json should be complete or else `json.loads()` will throw an error**

```
import json

header = """{"name":"sk"}"""
h = json.loads(header)
print(header)

with open('fields.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(h, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not `/`, it's `\`.

Second, it's not in your JSON, because you don't really seem to have a JSON here, you have just a string. And `json.dump()` converts the string into a string escaped for JSON format, replacing all `"` with `\"`.

By the way, you should not try to write incomplete JSON as a string yourself, it's better just to make a dictionary `{"fields":[]}`, then fill it with all values you want and later save into file through `json.dump()`.